# Connect django-server which are hosted by railway.app to react-server, also hosted by railway.app

Tags: reactjs, django, hosting, railway

I'm trying to connect my running Django-server to my running react-"server", but I don't know how... I have done the task with my apache-server, but can't manage to do it in railways.app. Any helpful minds out there who can guide me to my goal?